# How to apply list function to textacy generator obj in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, textacy

I'm applying the 'list' function to a pandas col which contains generator objects, in attempt to show all generator objects in col. When applying, the col returns empty lists. The 'subject_verb_object_triples' is a textacy function (https://chartbeat-labs.github.io/textacy/_modules/textacy/extract.html)

print(sp500news3)

```
date_publish    title
79944   2007-01-29 19:08:35 <generator object subject_verb_object_triples at 0x1a42713550>
181781  2007-12-14 19:39:06 <generator object subject_verb_object_triples at 0x1a42713410>
213175  2008-01-22 11:17:19 <generator object subject_verb_object_triples at 0x1a427135f0>
93554   2008-01-22 18:52:56 <generator object subject_verb_object_triples at 0x1a427135a0>

In []: sp500news3["title"].apply(list)
Out []: 79944     []
        181781    []
        213175    [] ...
```

The expected output are tuples such as the following:

```
[(Sky proposal, is, matter), (Sky proposal, is, Mays spokesman)], 
[(Women, lag, Intel report)], 
[(Amazon, expected, to unveil)], 
[(Goldman Sachs, raising, billion)], 
[(MHP, opens, books)], 
[(Disney, hurls, magic), (Disney, hurls, moolah)], 
[(Amazon, offering, loans), (Amazon, offering, to)], ....
```

How can I display the expected output in my dataframe?

Comment: What is the expected output ? Is there a question ? How can we help ?

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte - have updated q

Comment: Could you use a `lambda` here? `lambda x: [a for a in x]`

Comment: you probably want `sp500news3["title"].apply(lambda x: list(x)`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander this still returns empty lists

Comment: as does the suggestion from @C.Nivs

Comment: Were the generator already consumed? @C.Nivs's solution `sp500news3["title"].apply(lambda x: [a for a in x])` should give you the output expected.  Run fresh data against this line and report your findings.

Comment: I believe using `textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples` in the form `sp500news3['title'].apply(textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples)` yields an empty result for some reason @Idlehands

Comment: Then it's probably best you create a [MCVE].

Comment: Also, you're not supposed to `.apply(textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples)`. Use `.apply(lambda x: [a for a in x])` as advised!  Your example is only going to return you a generator function, not the actual results.

Comment: generators are a one-time-use only object. Once you exhaust the generator, it's gone. So you'll have to re-run how you built that dataframe

Answer (score 0):

**I have tested below code and it is working fine**

```
import textacy
import pandas as pd
from textacy import preprocessing
pd.options.display.max_colwidth=-1
df['<New Column name'>]=df['<Your column name that needs to be processed>'].apply(lambda x:preprocessing.normalize_whitespace(preprocessing.remove_punctuation(str(x))))
```